# maven clean install fails with XJC error

Tags: java, maven, xsd, xjc

I am getting XJC (generating source from XSD) error while building a project using *mvn clean install*. Weird thing is, when the same code is built in other machine the same is getting successful and sources are getting generated from XSDs. Below is the Exception, I am getting.

```
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.1.13/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar (3031 KB at 27.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Generating source...
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[ERROR] file:/home/proj-app/message-converter/msg-cnvrtr-domain/src/main/resources/MSG-CNVRTR-DB.xsd[133,60]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/proj-app/message-converter/proj-domain/src/main/resources/MSG-CNVRTR-DB.xsd; lineNumber: 133; columnNumber: 60; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'msg:ChannelType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4156)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4139)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1745)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:194)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:3612)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:636)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:572)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:101)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:357)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
```

I guess this is some problem with my environment setup as the same is compiling in other machines. Can anyone put some light on this please?

Comment: Please provide some context information. (java version(s), operating system(s), encoding used on the machines for the project(s), ...)

Comment: Hi, Please find below the details:
JDK: 1.8.0_121 (Open JDK)
Maven: 3.2.5
OS: Ubuntu (xenial)

Comment: Please also include the pom.xml file content

Comment: Added in the answer